# Xcode上でiOSアプリをビルドする時にTeamとプロビジョニングプロファイルを指定しないとエラーが出る

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

Xcode8.2.1を使っています。
あるPushノーティフィケーションを利用したプロジェクトをビルドしようとしているのですが、
Teamを指定しないとSigningのStatusに
Signing for "IdentifyName" requires a development team.
とエラーが出、個人のappleIDを入力すると添付のようにプロビジョニングプロファイルが要求されます。
この場合、DeveloperアカウントがないとRunもBuildも出来ないのでしょうか。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 2):

***この場合、DeveloperアカウントがないとRunもBuildも出来ないのでしょうか。***

結論から言うとその通りです。

Appleのプッシュ通知サービス(APNs)を使用したアプリを開発するためには、開発するアプリのアプリケーションID(App ID)の登録と、そのアプリケーションIDに対する証明書作成等の手順が必要で、それらが済んでいないと、ビルドに必要なプロビジョニングプロファイルの自動生成等が行われません。

で、上記の手順を実行するためにはApple Developer Programに登録済みのDeveloperアカウントが必要ですので、それがなければビルドできない、当然実行することもできない、と言うことになります。

[ローカル通知／リモート通知プログラミングガイド](https://developer.apple.com/jp/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html)
　[プロビジョニングおよび開発](https://developer.apple.com/jp/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ProvisioningDevelopment.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH104-SW1)

[アプリケーションの配布に関するガイド](https://developer.apple.com/jp/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html)
　[プッシュ通知の設定をする](https://developer.apple.com/jp/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AddingCapabilities/AddingCapabilities.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH26-SW6)

"iOS プッシュ通知 開発手順"あたりで検索すれば、日本語で詳細に手順を紹介した記事が見つかるので、そちらの方が上記のAppleの公式ドキュメントよりもわかりやすいかも知れません。

残念ながらプッシュ通知の機能を持ったアプリについて、Developerアカウント無しにお試しプロジェクトを作って動作内容を確認するような手段は用意されていません。